# If $0⩽x⩽y⩽z⩽w⩽u$ and $x+y+z+w+u=1$, prove $xw+wz+zy+yu+ux⩽\frac15$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, lagrange-multiplier, substitution, buffalo-way

> If $0⩽x⩽y⩽z⩽w⩽u$ and $x+y+z+w+u=1$, prove$$
> xw+wz+zy+yu+ux⩽\frac15.
> $$

I have tried using AM-GM, rearrangement, and Cauchy-Schwarz inequalities, but I always end up with squared terms. For example, applying AM-GM to each pair directly gives$$
x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+u^2 ⩾ xw + wz + zy + yu + ux,
$$
but I cannot seem to continue from here or use $x + y + z + w + u = 1$. Other inequalities like Chebyshev's rely on the multiplied pairs to be in order from least to greatest or vice versa, so I am stuck here.

Comment: @Alex Francisco Why you changed my editing? In my solution I used BW and substitutions. Also, there is a solution by the LM method.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg If some specific methods are used in answers, it's fine to name out in the **answers**. However, the OP does **not** mandate that the inequality has to be proved by the methods in the two tags you attempted to add. Adding these tags would likely to cause the misconception that the OP wants to prove the inequality using those two methods only.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Also, could you at least have your own answer get a positive score first to make such edits?

Comment: @Alex Francisco I don't agree with you twice. Also, you can read my solution and understand that my solution is right. If some user down-voted it does not say that my solution is wrong. By the way, by my solution we can get the solution by AM-GM, but it does not say that it's better.

Comment: @Alex Francisco What do you think about my solution? I think four hours it's enough for  understanding. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy to solve this problem with the Lagrange multipliers

Calling

$$
L(x,y,z,w,u,\lambda) = \frac 15 -(xw+wz+zy+yu+ux)+\lambda(x+y+z+w+u-1)
$$

The stationary points are the solutions for

$$
\nabla L = (L_x,L_y,L_z,L_w,L_u,L_{\lambda})=0
$$

or

$$
\lambda -u-w = 0\\
\lambda -u-z = 0\\
\lambda -w-y = 0\\
\lambda -x-z = 0\\
\lambda -x-y = 0\\
u+w+x+y+z-1 = 0
$$

Solving this linear system we obtain

$$
x = y = z = w = u = \frac 15,\;\lambda = \frac25
$$

This point is the only tangent point between the surface $g(x,y,z,w,u)=\frac 15 -(xw+wz+zy+yu+ux)$ and the hyperplane $\Pi =x+y+z+w+u-1 = 0$

and  $g(x,y,z,w,u) \ge 0$ is located into one of the  semi-spaces delimited by $\Pi$ and also at the tangency point we have $g = 0$ with the values found before.

NOTE

This formulation is a short hand for

$$
L(x,y,z,w,u,\lambda,\epsilon) = \frac 15 -(xw+wz+zy+yu+ux)+\lambda_1(x+y+z+w+u-1)+\lambda_2(x-\epsilon_1^2)+\lambda_2(y-x-\epsilon_2^2)+\lambda_4(z-y-\epsilon_3^2)+\lambda_5(w-z-\epsilon_4^2)+\lambda_6(u-w-\epsilon_5^2)
$$

and the result should be the same as you can verify with a little patience.

Comment: I think your solution is wrong because you proved the inequality for all non-negative variables with sum $1$, which is wrong. Try $x=w=\frac{1}{2}$ and $y=z=u=0$.

Comment: At this point there is not tangency between $g$ and $\Pi$

Comment: Yes, of course. But why in  this point we'll get a maximal value. Where you used ordering of variables? Without this using my counterexample says that your solution is total wrong.

Comment: As you ask for ordering, follows this formulation included as a note in the actual answer. I used this first but it is more clumsy and I prefer the simpler one.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Consider $$ \Delta =\bigg\{x=(x_i)\in \mathbb{R}^5\bigg| \sum_i\
x_i=1,\ x_i\geq 0\bigg\}
$$

If $\sigma x =\sum_i\ x_ie_{i+1}$ where $e_i$ is a canonical basis
in $\mathbb{R}^5$, then define $$ f: \Delta\rightarrow \mathbb{R},\
f(x)=x\cdot \sigma (x) $$

Define $H=\bigg\{ v\in \mathbb{R}^n\bigg| \sum_i\ x_i=0\bigg\}$. For
$v\in H$, then
$$ \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \bigg|_{t=0}\ f(p+tv) = 2v\cdot \sigma (v) <0 \ \ast $$

(2) Proof of $\ast $ : If $\pi : \mathbb{R}^5\rightarrow H$ is orthogonal
projection, then $\{\pi (e_i)\}$ forms vertex set of tetrahedron $T$
in $H$. And $\sigma$ acts on the set transitively and note that
vertexes has an angle $>\frac{\pi}{2}$.

(3) So $f$ is a strict concave so that it has a global maximum. Here
$$f'(p+tv)\bigg|_{t=0} = p\cdot \{ \sigma (v) +\sigma^{-1}(v)\} =0 $$
 when $p=\frac{1}{5}\sum_{i}\ e_i$.

Hence $f(p)=\frac{1}{5}$

Answer (score -1):

The case where $xw+wz+zy+yu+ux$ is maximal will be where $x=y=z=w=u$. Here, they must all be $\frac15$, and plugging into the equation gives $5(\frac15)^2=\frac15$. So the expression is $\le\frac15$.

Comment: How do you prove that the expression is maximized when $x=y=z=w=u?$

Comment: @Danielxc One of my favorite tricks. The expression is symmetric, so if it has a maximum anywhere but $x = y = z = w = u$, then it must have multiple maxima. But the expression is also concave, a contradiction.

Answer (score -1):

Let $y=x+a$, $z=x+a+b$, $w=x+a+b+c$ and $u=x+a+b+c+d$.

Thus, $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are non-negatives and we need to prove that:
$$(x+y+z+u+w)^2\geq5(xw+wz+zy+yu+ux)$$ or
$$(5x+4a+3b+2c+d)^2\geq5(x(x+a+b+c)+(x+a+b+c)(x+a+b)+(x+a+b)(x+a)+(x+a)(x+a+b+c+d)+(x+a+b+c+d)x)$$ or
$$(5x+4a+3b+2c+d)^2\geq5(5x^2+(8a+6b+4c+2d)x+(a+b+c)(a+b)+(a+b)a+a(a+b+c+d))$$ or
$$(4a+3b+2c+d)^2\geq5((a+b+c)(a+b)+(a+b)a+a(a+b+c+d)),$$
which is obvious.

Done!